# How to insert data into a table without Id in query?

Tags: c#, sql, database, primary-key, sqlclient

I would like to know how use insert command in query without knowing the Id my table consists of Id || Dollars || UserName and my table name is creds

I've tried doing insert commands but i cant figure it out

I would just like to know how to get Id without knowing how many columns there are so say there are 3 columns but I dont know that how can I make a new column.

**ID is Primary Key**

```
INSERT INTO creds VALUES(Id, 50, 'UserName')
```

Comment: What do you mean by **Id** here? If it is an auto increment field in your database, then you do not need to know its value otherwise you would have to explicitly give its value during your insert.

Answer (score 10):

You should always list the columns when doing an `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO creds (dollars, username)
     VALUES (50, 'UserName');
```

If you want to list the `id` column, use `DEFAULT`:

```
INSERT INTO creds (id, dollars, username)
     VALUES (DEFAULT, 50, 'UserName');
```

Comment: Just an info: This won't work if you are using scalar properties in stored procedure. This will produce an error saying: "default or null are not allowed as explicit identity values"

Comment: @noobprogrammer . . . Your comment seems utterly irrelevant because the question has no mention whatsoever of a stored procedure.  However, you might have a question yourself, and I would encourage you to ask it.

Answer (score 3):

For insert actually, you don't need to know the Id

```
INSERT INTO creds (Id, Dollars, Username) VALUES(50, 2000, 'UserName')
```

If Id is Identity then you must not include it in the insert:

```
INSERT INTO creds (Dollars, Username) VALUES(2000, 'UserName')
```

You would need Id (probably primary key) only if you are updating table:

```
Update creds set username = 'New Username' where Id = 50
```

Answer (score 1):

If **"Id" column(field)"** is **auto-incrementable**, **"Id"** and **the value** are not needed for **"INSERT" query**:

```sql
                -- Don't need "Id" and the value
INSERT INTO creds (Dollars, Username) VALUES(2000, 'UserName')
```

If **"Id" column(field)"** is not **auto-incrementable**, **"Id"** and **the value** are needed for **"INSERT" query**:

```sql
                -- Here                       -- Here
INSERT INTO creds (Id, Dollars, Username) VALUES(13, 2000, 'UserName')
```

Answer (score -2):

It is not a good practice to leave the column name when inserting values in a table. But you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO creds VALUES(
(SELECT max(Id)+1 FROM creds), 50, 'UserName')
```

If Id is an integer primary key.